# Access nested objects property with pug

Tags: object, pug, pugjs

I have this object called obj in my pug template

```
{
  "property1": {
    "property1": {
      "property1": "value",
      "property2": "value",
      "property3": "value"
    },
    "property2": "value",
    "property3": "value"
  },
  "property2": "value",
  "property3": "value"
}
```

If i do

```
pre=obj
```

The object is displayed correctly. 
But if I want to access its nested properties like

```
pre=obj.property1.property1
```

For some reasons its not rendering.

Same if I do `p=obj.property1.property1.property1`

What am I missing? 
Thanks

Here is my exact code snippet:

```
  .box-body
    -session_details.forEach(function(session_detail) {
      .row
        .col-md-1=moment(session_detail.create_time).calendar()
        .col-md-1=moment(session_detail.create_time).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
        .col-md-1=session_detail.intent
        .col-md-4
          p #{session_detail.request.type}
          pre=session_detail.request

        .col-md-5
          pre=session_detail.response
    - });
```

And here is the exact output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx1Tt.jpg

As you can see, the `p #{session_detail.request.type}` is not displayed for some reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It's been asked already but I don't have enough reputation to flag as duplicate.

To answer your question, use hash and curly braces.

```
p #{property1.property1}
```

I don't think you need the equal sign though.

Comment: Hey Roger,
Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried your solution but it didnt work. I have updated my question with more context. Feel free to let me know if you see where the issue is coming from. 
Thanks

Comment: Based on your example with the property1, if your key is a string (wrapped in ""), then you would have to access it like so


    #{obj["property1"]["property1"]["property1"]}. If you remove the quotes in your key, then you can access it with obj.property1.property1.property1. Otherwise, I can't see where the problem is, as I tested in my .pug template and it is working for me.

Comment: Using my example, I would do `p #{session_detail["locale"]}` to access locale key? Because this one seems not to work also. Neither does `p #{session_detail.locale}`

Comment: I don't know what to say. It's working on mine. If I have, at the top of my .pug template -var test = {test: {test: {test: "test"}}} I can access it by doing p #{test.test.test.test} It would output "test". How is your session_detail object declared?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `obj.find()` instead of `obj.findOne()` to get your instance of the "obj" model, then an array with one object (`[obj]`) will be returned, instead of just the obj itself.  If that's the case, you won't be able to access the properties of it without accessing the index in the array first (`obj[0].property1`).